# React Navigation: How to update child state when parent state gets updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

The data of parent is passed to child via:
this.props.navigation.navigate("foo", {data: data});

Comment: what you are asking is a basic react pattern. if you showed what you tried, we could assist better.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever one navigates to any screen, the current state of objects is sent as props to the navigated component.

Having said that,  the navigate function should be associated with a function/component placed in `render()`. So, if data is updated, `render()` gets called again and you're navigated to the new screen with updated data.